# If $V$ is a subspace of a finite dimensional inner product vector space, prove that $(V ^ \perp)^\perp = V$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, proof-writing, orthogonality

For any subspace $V$ of a finite dimensional inner product vector space, prove that $(V ^ \perp)^\perp = V$.

My proof is below.  I request verification, critique, or improvement.

*Note: Other proofs are available.  This question is to verify or critique* this *proof.*

---

**Lemma 1:** For any vector space $V$, $\dim V = \operatorname{codim} V^\perp$.

Proof: Let $\{v_n\}$ be a basis for $V$, and $[V]^\top$ be the matrix where $\operatorname{row} i = v_i$.  Clearly $\operatorname{rank} [V]^\top = \dim V $. The nullspace of $[V]^\top$ is precisely $V^\perp$, since any vector $x$ is both in the nullspace of $[V]^\top$ and in $V^\perp$ if and only if $x$ is orthogonal to each $v_i$.   Thus, $\operatorname{codim} V^\perp = \operatorname{codim nullspace} [V]^\top = \operatorname{rank} [V]^\top = \dim V$.

**Lemma 2:** For any vector spaces $V, W$, if $V \subset W$ and $\dim V = \dim W$, then $V = W$.

Proof: Any basis of $V$ must be a subset of $W$ and therefore a basis of $W$, implying that $V = W$.

**Main Proof:** By applying Lemma 1 twice, we have $\dim (V ^ \perp)^\perp = \dim V$.  Furthermore, since, by definition, any $v \in V$ is in $(V ^ \perp)^\perp$, we have $V \subset (V ^ \perp)^\perp$.  Since the perp of a vector space is itself a vector space, we can apply Lemma 2, and have $V = (V ^ \perp)^\perp$.

**Remarks:** This proof assumes that vector spaces have a finite dimension.  I do not know how to determine if it holds for infinite dimensional vector spaces.

---

Is the proof above correct, rigorous, and well written? How could it be improved?

---

### Update

As recommended by the comments, I've added that $V$ is a **subspace of a finite dimensional inner product vector space**.  With that stipulation, is the proof correct, rigorous, and well written? How could it be improved?

Comment: Is $V$ a subspace or the entire vector space?

Comment: The question makes no sense. Is $V$ a subspace of a *finite-dimensional* inner product space? Nothing to critique until you set it up precisely and correctly.

Comment: @MathFail Fixed: $V$ is a subspace.

Comment: @TedShifrin I edited it to state that $V$ is a subspace.  Re finite-dimensional, see the remarks.  And yes, this is an inner product space, as implied by the usage of $\perp$.  Does that provide a proper set up? If not, let me know what else is needed.

Comment: It does not necessarily hold for infinite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ah, thanks for pointing that out. For some reason, I thought OP was talking about dual space. Removed my comment for not causing further confusion :)

Comment: It's mainly correct, though I would say that the key part of the argument isn't all the Lemmas, but rather the claim that $V\subseteq (V^{\perp})^{\perp}$ (which holds for infinite dimensional spaces as well). Another way of showing the codimension is to show that $V\cap V^{\perp}=\{\mathbf{0}\}$ and that $V+V^{\perp}$ is the whole space, by taking the orthogonal projection onto $V$.

Comment: Lemma 1 is not well phrased. "For any vector space $V$" when you actually mean for any subspace $V$ of a vector space $W$, with codimension relative to $W$. (The fact that you are using $V$ for a **subspace** of an unnamed vector space is already bound to cause confusion, since usually if there is only one space named, it is the ambient space, and $V$ is a common name for that...)